# In MongoDB, if collection is dropped, indexes dropped automatically as well?

Tags: mongodb, collections, indexing, document

If I create a collection in Mongo, and after adding documents to this collection I use `ensureIndex()` to create an index on, say, a number field on a document in this collections, if I drop the collection, do I have to recreate the index?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Indexes are dropping on collection drop. You need to recreate an index.

You may want to not to drop collection but remove all items in it with `db.collection_name.remove({})`. It will take more resources but leave your indexes. Actually it will need to delete all index data. That is why it is more preferred to drop the whole collection and recreate indexes after that.

Comment: Can I create an index on an empty collection?

Comment: Yes you can. The collection will be created when you create the index.

Comment: `remove()` can take a long time on big collections. `drop()` is much faster, but has the downside of removing all the indexes, as has already been noted.

Answer (score 14):

I just did this on a collection with 10 indexes and didn't want to manually recreate those.  You can accomplish a drop and recreate with indexes with the following three lines in the mongo shell:

```
var indexes = db.collection.getIndexKeys().splice(1)
db.collection.drop();
indexes.forEach(function(el){ db.collection.ensureIndex(el, {background:true}); })
```

This isn't smart enough to handle unique or sparse indexes but I think that would be fairly easy to support by using the output of getIndexes() instead.  I didn't need that, so I didn't do it.

The splice(1) is just to remove the index on _id, since that will be auto created.

Comment: many thanks, but `{background:true}` erased my indexes, without it works great

Comment: that's because `{background:true}` create ur indexes in background, so when u run ur tests or something ur indexes may not be recreated yet

Answer (score 4):

Dropping a collection does drop all the indexes, as you suspect, so when you recreate the collection (either explicitly, or implicitly by adding new documents) you will need to recreate any indexes you need to have present. The default index on `_id` is created for you automatically.

Comment: Ok, understood, is there any harm in calling ensureIndex() multiple times on the same collection if the index already exists?

Comment: No harm. Minor performance impact to check if the index you're trying to ensure is already there or not.