# After Dropping Collection, Collection is re-made when saving first records, but why aren't its indexes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below is my method for dropping a mongodb Collection.  It works, but after saving the first records the collection is re-created without the appropriate indexes.

Since my Model has three properties with `unique: true`, I need those indexes to be created, so that no duplicates are saved.  Why aren't the instances being created, and how do I auto-create them?

**Model:**

```
var ObjectSchema = new Schema({
    propertyone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    propertytwo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    propertythree: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    }
});
```

**Method - for dropping the collection**

```
exports.dropCollection = function(collectionName, callback) {
    console.log("Dropping Collection: " + collectionName);
    // Drop in collection name string
    var collection = mongoose.connection.collections[collectionName]
    collection.drop(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, null) 
        } else {
            console.log("Collection Deleted")
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple reason is that you dropped the collection and the indexes are `attached` to the collection. Your question is basically the reverse for of this existing post:

[In MongoDB, if collection is dropped, indexes dropped automatically as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506345/in-mongodb-if-collection-is-dropped-do-indexes-get-dropped-automatically)

What you likely want is [remove](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/). With no arguments or an empty query document it will remove all documents in the collection. The indexes however remain.

Comment: Thanks!  The remove method worked and I also needed to set ensureIndexes above like WiredPrairie suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose automatically creates the indexes specified by schemas at startup. If you drop a collection at runtime, which deletes all data and all indexes at runtime, you'll either need to restart the application, or on a `Model`, you can recreate them when necessary:

```
MyModel.ensureIndexes(function() {
    // callback after indexes have been created
});
```